# Send Json to springboot using postman

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

**Starter**

```
package com.origin.starter;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@EnableJpaRepositories("com.origin.starter")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.origin.starter" })
@EntityScan("com.origin.starter")  
@SpringBootApplication
public class OriginServerSideApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OriginServerSideApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
package com.origin.starter.artistcontroller;

import java.util.List;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.origin.starter.artistservice.ArtistService;
import com.origin.starter.model.Artist;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/origin/group")
public class ArtistController {

    @Autowired
    private ArtistService artistService;

    @PostMapping("/artistInfo")
    public void createHero(@Valid @RequestBody Artist artistInfo) {
        System.out.println(artistInfo);
        artistService.createArtist(artistInfo);

    }

}
```

**Entity(Artist.java)**

```
package com.origin.starter.model;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Getter @Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "Artist")
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Artist {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long artistId;
    private String artistName;
    private int artistAge;
    private String artistDateOfBirth;
    private String artistLanguage;
    private String[] artistSocialMediaURLs ;
    List<Movie> movies;
}
```

**Movie.java**

```
package com.origin.starter.model;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter @Setter 
@NoArgsConstructor 
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Movie {

    private String movieName;
    private String movieHero;
}
```

**Service**

```
package com.origin.starter.artistservice;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.origin.starter.herorepository.ArtistRepository;
import com.origin.starter.model.Artist;

@Service
public class ArtistService {

    @Autowired  
    private ArtistRepository artistRepository;

    public void createArtist(@Valid Artist artistInfo) {

        artistRepository.save(artistInfo);
    }

}
```

**Repositary**

```
package com.origin.starter.herorepository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.origin.starter.model.Artist;

public interface ArtistRepository extends JpaRepository<Artist, Long> {

}
```

**MyInputJson**

```
[
    {
        "artistName": "xyz",
        "artistAge": 20,
        "artistDateOfBirth": "10/12/92",
        "artistLanguage": "english",        
        "artistSocialMediaURLs": [
           "fb",
           "Insta"
        ],
        "movies": {
            "movieName": "racegurram",    
            "movieHero": "alluarjun"
        },  
]
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=Origin-Server
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=******
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true

## Hibernate Properties
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = 
org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

#Sevlet Context-Path
server.servlet.context-path=/origin-group
```

I am getting 404 Error in postman without any exception clue.... no exception clue even in console....

i got something in postman like ...

*{
    "timestamp": "2019-12-14T09:37:06.245+0000",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/origin-group/origin/group/artistInfo"
}*

this is the url which iam hitting **localhost:8080/origin-group/origin/group/artistInfo**

**Update**

After debugging my code i changed few lines of code ....
Now i got an error  like....

```
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]





org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: artist, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(anchoring)]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1803) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at com.origin.starter.OriginServerSideApplication.main(OriginServerSideApplication.java:16) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: artist, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(anchoring)]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:403) ~[spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378) ~[spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1862) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1799) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: artist, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(anchoring)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:488) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:455) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:227) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:624) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:267) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:343) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:461) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1249) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Where origin-group path is configured?

Comment: those details are available in **applications.properties**

Comment: Status of response is 404, which means you are making request to wrong resource. Check your url. You can find more here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: @SivaReddy Your package name is incorrect at configuration

Comment: You send array, but your code takes single item: `@PostMapping("/artistInfo")
    public void createHero(@Valid @RequestBody Artist artistInfo) {`

Comment: Is your application started successfully. Also what is the url you are hitting on postman ?

Comment: this is the url which iam hitting **http://localhost:8080/origin-group/origin/group/artistInfo**

Comment: try removing the server.servlet.context-path=/origin-group and add a sample controller method with getmapping. Also , Please try changing return type to responseEntity for the post mapping.

Comment: could you also share the startup logs, spring prints  all the request mappings that the application would support.

Answer (score 0):

Your spring configuration is incorrect. Look at your configuration:

```
 @EnableJpaRepositories("my.package.base.*")
```

Here package name is wrong. Replace all package with correct name, like:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.origin.starter")
```

Comment: @SivaReddy, Check your URL. Your requesting with wrong path.

Answer (score -1):

use "@repository" annotation in ArtistRepository